# Round slider and transitions

Tags: jquery, css, slider, transition

How to create a similar slider to it like on http://www.7h34.fr/ and transitions between subpages?

What plugins can be used?

Do you have any examples?

Comment: A lot of `css` and `js`, it's a wordpress website that uses a custom-made theme.

Comment: I know but I would static want to do without wordpress in html and jquery